# how to update a value in firebase realtime database using Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I went though the firebase docs for updating a value in realtime database using Cloud Functions for Firebase, but am not able to understand.

My database structure is

```
{   
 "user" : {
    "-KdD1f0ecmVXHZ3H3abZ" : {
      "email" : "ksdsd@sdsd.com",
      "first_name" : "John",
      "last_name" : "Smith",
      "isVerified" : false
    },
    "-KdG4iHEYjInv7ljBhgG" : {
      "email" : "superttest@sds213123d.com",
      "first_name" : "Max1",
      "last_name" : "Rosse13131313l",
      "isVerified" : false
    },
    "-KdGAZ8Ws6weXWo0essF" : {
      "email" : "superttest@sds213123d.com",
      "first_name" : "Max1",
      "last_name" : "Rosse13131313l",
      "isVerified" : false
    } 
}
```

I want to update the isVerified using database trigger cloud functions. I don't know how to update a database value using cloud functions (language : Node.JS)

I wrote a code to automatically update the value of the key 'isVerified' of a user, when the user is created by using database trigger onWrite. My code is

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.userVerification = functions.database.ref('/users/{pushId}')
    .onWrite(event => {
    // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    var eventSnapshot = event.data;

    if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    eventSnapshot.update({
        "isVerified": true
    });
});
```

but when i deploy the code, and add a user to the database, the cloud function log shows the below error

```js
TypeError: eventSnapshot.child(...).update is not a function
    at exports.userVerification.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:10:36)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:35:20
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
```

Comment: The Cloud Functions documentation has a section and a set of examples for this. Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: I am not able to understand the example give in the docs, i need help in understanding the same or someother example code to study with. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is unlikely that somebody will just come up with a better example than what is in the documentation. Instead of asking for that, show what you've already tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Hi, i have updated the post with the details of what i tried and the error that i got. Kindly for addressing it, my mistake, i should have given details first itself. Kindly help me out.

Comment: @ThooyavanManivaasakar I'm having nearly same problem , I want to update a field in Users/{UserID}/(this field) when new user is created . I tried these solutions but nothing worked for me .Would you like to help me ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are trying to call `update()` on a DeltaSnapshot object.  There is no such method on that type of object.

```js
var eventSnapshot = event.data;
eventSnapshot.update({
  "isVerified": true
});
```

`event.data` is a [DeltaSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot).  If you want to change the data at the location of the change represented by this object. Use its `ref` property to get a hold of a Reference object:

```js
var ref = event.data.ref;
ref.update({
  "isVerified": true
});
```

Also, if you are reading or writing the database in a function, you should [always return a Promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) that indicates when the change is complete:

```js
return ref.update({
  "isVerified": true
});
```

I would recommend taking Frank's advice from the comments and study the existing [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/) and [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to better understand how Cloud Functions works.

Comment: Thank you Doug, and also you too Frank, Thanks to you too

Comment: @ThooyavanManivaasakar can you please share your final function as an answer?  This answer still has some ambiguity and the sample code and documentation have much to be questioned -- hence your question, as-is my identical question.

Comment: Hi @mobibob, the current answer seems to be clear and helped me out, so Kindly let me know your exact problem, so that I can help out accordingly